# Structuring a Table with the results from CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

i am having a query like

```
     $report_attrid=$this->Report->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Report.report_id'=>$report_id,'Report.user_id'=>$userId)));


   foreach($report_attrid as & $reportattrid):

      $reportattrid['Report']['attr']=$this->Attribute->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Attribute.id','Attribute.label'),'conditions'=>array('Attribute.id'=>$reportattrid['Report']['attribute_id'],'Attribute.form_id'=>$report_form_id),'order'=>'Attribute.sequence_no'));

      $reportattrid['Report']['value']=$this->Result->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Result.label','Result.value','Result.submitter_id','Result.submitter'),'conditions'=>array('Result.attribute_id'=>$reportattrid['Report']['attribute_id'],'Result.form_id'=>$report_form_id),'order'=>'Result.id'));



   endforeach;


        $this->set('Report_attrid',$report_attrid);
```

1.the first one for  $report_attrid will gives me the all the datas needed for my report

as

```
       id Report_id title form_id  attribute_id
        1  1         r1    24          69
        2  1         r2    24          72
```

2.And then foreach attribute_id , i am fetching the Attributes label from my attribute table in the second query  $reportattrid['Report']['attr'];

3.
And then Foreach Reports attribute_id i am trying to fetch the entries from my results table using   $reportattrid['Report']['value'] which gives as

At first when attribute_id = 69 it returns 2 rows

as

```
    id form_id attribute_id value
     1    24       69         A
     2    24       69         B
```

Then attribute_id = 72 it returns 2 rows

as

```
        id form_id attribute_id value
        3    24       72         C
        4    24       69         D
```

Everything retriving correctly but now

i am trying to build a table to display in my view

using

```
  <table id="sampletable">
  <thead>
       <?php foreach ($Report_attrid as $report1): ?>

 <th id="headerid<?php echo $report1['Report']['attr'][0]['Attribute']['id'];?>"><?php echo $report1['Report']['attr'][0]['Attribute']['label'];?>
    </th>                 

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
  <?php foreach ($Report_attrid as $report2): ?>

                  <tr>     <?php foreach ($report2['Report']['value'] as $report3): ?>

                              <td> <?php echo $report3['Result']['value'];?>   </td>

                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </tr>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
</table>
```

which displays me like

```
     Firstname experience
       A           B
       C           D
```

but i need the table as

```
       Firstname experience
        A           C
        B           D
```

how to do so?? please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your model code for Report, Attribute, Result. I think that you could set up the relations better, to return the data with one call.

From the code it looks as if:

- Attribute hasMany Report & Report belongsTo Attribute
- Attribute hasMany Result & Result belongsTo Attribute

If you set up those relations in the models [Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) then you should just need to make one call and all the related record will come out too.

Once you have got the models done let me know, and we can see whats next...